# Data Binding DataGridView to ComboBox Throwing Null Value Exception

Tags: c#, linq, data-binding, combobox, null

I am trying to to bind data from *DataGridView* in two ComboBoxes. In ComboBox one is *cbosearchby* and other *cbosearchvalue*. *cbosearchby* is working perfectly but when select searchvalue error being thrown. Please help me to sort out it.

Error is :

```
Value cannot be null.Parameter name: value
```

Here is my code:

```
    private void cboSearchBy_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cboSearchValue.Items.Clear();
        cboSearchValue.Text = "";

        if (cboSearchBy.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            string[] sValues = new string[0];

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (!cboSearchValue.Items.Contains(dr.Cells[cboSearchBy.SelectedItem.ToString()].Value))
                {
                    cboSearchValue.Items.Add(dr.Cells[cboSearchBy.SelectedItem.ToString()].Value);
                    Array.Resize(ref sValues, sValues.Length + 1);
                    sValues[sValues.Length - 1] = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells[cboSearchBy.SelectedItem.ToString()].Value);
                }
            }

            source.AddRange(sValues);
            cboSearchValue.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
        }
    }
```

Comment: On which statement are you getting the above error ?

Comment: if (!cboSearchValue.Items.Contains(dr.Cells[cboSearchBy.SelectedItem.ToString()].Value))

Comment: this is giving error

Answer (score 1):

If the `value` you're passing to `Contains()` is `null`, then it'll throw an exception.

Here's what's going on internally when you call the [`Contains()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ComboBox.cs,0b413bd31ff60f84,references) method:

```
 public bool Contains(object value)
 {
     return IndexOf(value) != -1;
 }

 public int IndexOf(object value)
 {
     if (value == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

     return InnerList.IndexOf(value);
 }
```

To fix this, you need to check for `null` separately:

```
var searchValue = dr.Cells[cboSearchBy.SelectedItem.ToString()].Value;

if (searchValue != null && !cboSearchValue.Items.Contains(searchValue))
{
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here could be with this statement :

```
cboSearchValue.Items.Clear();
```

This is called immediately at the entry point of your functions and this will erase all items from your drop-down. And further in your code, you are using `Contains()` on that same drop-down. Since the drop-down will already be empty, you wont be able to use `Contains()`, suffice to say that you will receive an exception there. You might want to remove that statement from there.

I dont know what exactly your logic here is, but you can try according to the above mentioned thing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: no its not working if i dont clear it how can i add new values to it.

Comment: How can you check for `Contains()` after you have cleared it ? There will obviously be no values in it. You can clear it after you condition is satisfied and you are now ready to insert new values. Just before the code for adding new values.